# Vercel/Express JS "Couldn't read properties of undefined ("Collection")"

Tags: mongodb, express, vercel

Trying to deploy my express app to vercel... runs fine locally, I've added the MongoDB as an environment variable in vercel, however it doesn't seem to call the database correctly? Not sure where I'm going wrong...

Code to connect to the DB:

The error:

```js
undefined
Unhandled Promise Rejection     {"errorType":"Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection","errorMessage":"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'collection')","reason":{"errorType":"TypeError","errorMessage":"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'collection')","stack":["TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'collection')","    at /var/task/api/routes/user.js:37:10","    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)"]},"promise":{},"stack":["Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'collection')","    at process.<anonymous> (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1188:17)","    at process.emit (node:events:525:35)","    at emit (node:internal/process/promises:149:20)","    at processPromiseRejections (node:internal/process/promises:283:27)","    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:32)"]}
Unknown application error occurred
Runtime.Unknown
```

```js
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
const Db = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
const client = new MongoClient(Db, {
  useNewUrlParser: true
});

let _db;

module.exports = {
  connectToServer: function (callback) {
    client.connect(async function (err, db) {
      // Verify we got a good "db" object
      if (db)
      {
        _db = await db.db("preview");
        console.log("Successfully connected to MongoDB.");
      } else {
        console.log("Couldn't connect to MongoDB")
      }
      return callback(err);
         });
  },

  getDb: function () {
    return _db;
  },
};
```

My Index:

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
require("dotenv").config({path: "./config.env"});
const port = process.env.PORT || 5432;
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(require("./api/routes/auth"));
app.use(require("./api/routes/user"));
app.use(require("./api/routes/card"))
const dbo = require("./api/db/conn");

app.listen(port, () => {
    dbo.connectToServer(function (err) {
        if (err) console.error(err);

    });
    console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port}`);
});
```

My route:

```
userRoutes.route("/user").get(async function (req, res) {
    const db_connect = dbo.getDb("preview");
    console.log(await db_connect);
    db_connect
        .collection("users")
        .find({})
        .toArray(function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.json(result);
        });
});
```

The exact same MONGODB_URI is in my projects config.env as well as the Vercel environment variables

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here?

It should return a list of users

Comment: To add, I've created a NextJS API to do this same particular request, which works fine with Vercel, I just don't want to convert all my express routes to use NextJS API routes...

Comment: `getDb: function () {` has no arguments, then your passing preview in `.getDb("preview")`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone You're totally right, but unfortunately that didn't solve it - getting the same error